Matlab error solving symbolic systems of equations as functions of time
I have the following system of differential equations that arose form circuit analysis where the following simplification was made.
Simplification of equations
The systems of equations is as follows:
System of Equations
I created 2 MATLAB files, the first where I define each I_x as a symbolic variable and a second file where I define each I_x as a function of time I_x(t). When I try to find I_4 as a function of time in file 2. I get an error
error: structure has no member 'I4'
error: called from
    Gauging_Circuit at line 12 column 1

Below are the tests I preformed:
% File 1
syms I1 I2 I3 I4 R1 R2 R3 C1 C2 C3 Vi;
eqn1 = Vi == I1*((1/C1) + R1) + I2*(-(1/C1)) +              I3*(0) +            I4*(0);
eqn2 = Vi == I1*(-(1/C1)) +     I2*((1/C1)+(1/C2)+(1/C3)) + I3*(0) +            I4*(0);
eqn3 = Vi == I1*(0) +           I2*(-(1/C3)) +              I3*((1/C3) + R3) +  I4*(0);
eqn4 = Vi == I1*(0) +           I2*(-(1/C2)) +              I3*(0) +            I4*((1/C2)+R2);

% Try lin solve, If it doesnt work, Try solve function below
%[A, B, C, D] = equationsToMatrix([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [I1, I2, I3, I4]);
%X = linsolve(A,B);

sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [I1, I2, I3, I4]);
disp(sol.I4)

File 1 output:
Output From file 1 Screenshot
When I try to make each current a function of time I_x(t) I get an error. Below is the code and output from file 2.
% File 2
syms I1(t) I2(t) I3(t) I4(t) R1 R2 R3 C1 C2 C3 Vi(t);
eqn1 = Vi == I1(t)*((1/C1) + R1) +  I2(t)*(-(1/C1)) +               I3(t)*(0) +           I4(t)*(0);
eqn2 = Vi == I1(t)*(-(1/C1)) +      I2(t)*((1/C1)+(1/C2)+(1/C3)) +  I3(t)*(0) +           I4(t)*(0);
eqn3 = Vi == I1(t)*(0) +            I2(t)*(-(1/C3)) +               I3(t)*((1/C3) + R3) + I4(t)*(0);
eqn4 = Vi == I1(t)*(0) +            I2(t)*(-(1/C2)) +               I3(t)*(0) +           I4(t)*((1/C2)+R2);

% Try lin solve, If it doesnt work, Try solve function below
%[A, B, C, D] = equationsToMatrix([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [I1, I2, I3, I4]);
%X = linsolve(A,B);

sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [I1(t), I2(t), I3(t), I4(t)]);
disp(sol.I4)

File 2 Output (Actual name is "Gauging_Circuit"):
error: structure has no member 'I4'
error: called from
    Gauging_Circuit at line 12 column 1

Why am I getting this error? When I change both files so that line 12 disp(sol.I4) becomes disp(sol), I get the exact same outputs but addressing I4 gives me an error in the second file.

What is the purpose of the second file? What do you expect to gain by adding the “(t)” everywhere?

I originally made it because I wanted to take the derivative of Ix as a function of time using the diff() function. This particular example is simple because each coefficient is a constant, So I can do it manually, but there will be change in the future that I'm not aware of at the moment where these coefficients will become a function of time and there will be many more equations to include.
